# Load page with HTML from web storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, local-storage

I'm testing a concept for an application using local storage and need to know the best way of loading the content after storing it.

Essentially the app will prefetch content, store it locally and then server it in a new page upon request. I need users to be able to click a link (mysite.com/article1.html) and instead of having the browser make the HTTP request for the page, just load the HTML that has been stored locally.

So how do I load the "localNews" value instead of making an HTTP for the same page?

```
var storeUrl;
var localNews;

$('a').click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
storeUrl = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: storeUrl,
    cache: true,
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function(html) {
    localNews = html;
    console.log(localNews);
    localStorage.setItem('storeUrl', 'localNews');
});
});
```

Comment: I think this link could prevent you from reinventing what yet exists : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: you forgot event in $('a').click(function(event) {

Comment: @dystroy Correct me if i'm wrong but this wouldn't work if we're using a PHP templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var storeUrl;
    var localNews;

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        storeUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        if (localStorage.getItem(storeUrl)) {
            //load local
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: storeUrl,
                cache: true,
                crossDomain: true
            }).done(function(html) {
                localNews = html;
                console.log(localNews);
                localStorage.setItem(storeUrl, localNews);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can see where you're going with this but my question was more how to load the actual content inside of the if statement that you added.

Comment: you can append it to body, or load into an iframe

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to load a local file via Ajax? Can be done, but just have to do a few small adjustments to your Ajax call.  So change this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: storeUrl,
    cache: true,
    crossDomain: true
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: storeUrl,
    cache: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
```

Note the `async` and `datatype` and `contentType`. It has been a while since I coded this, but I believe the key parameter is `async` but the `datatype` and `contentType` are needed as well.